# Reversing an Array Results In SegFault

Tags: c++

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {
    int k, in[k],reversea[k],i,m,n;
    cin>>k;
    for (i=0;i<k;i++){
        cin>>in[i];
    }
    for (m=k-1;m>=0;m--){
        for (n=0;n<k;n++){
            in[m]=reversea[n];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        cout<<reversea[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why it says segmentation fault even before i start debugging it.  I compile another one on calculating the frequency of 1, 5, and 10 in an array of k numbers, and it says the same thing...
Here is the other one:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k,i,m,n,count5,count1,count10;
    int input[k];
    cin>>k;
    for (i=0;i<k;i++){
        cin>>input[i];
    }//input all the numbers
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        if (input[i]=1){
            count1++;
        }
        if (input[i]=5){
            count5++;
        }
        if (input[i]=10){
            count10++;
        }
    }
    cout<<count1<<"\n"<<count5<<"\n"<<count10<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me.  Thanks.

Comment: _"I have no idea why it says segmentation fault even before i start debugging it"_ Well, when you debug it, you'll find out!

Answer (score 5):

On this line

```
int k, in[k],reversea[k]
```

How are you supposed to initialize an array with `k` elements if `k` isn't initialized? The size of an array must be known at *compile time* not *run time*. If `k` isn't know until run time, use a `std::vector`

```
int k;
std::cin >> k;
std::vector<int> in(k);
std::vector<int> reversea(k);
```

Comment: @harry47341 `in[k]` when `k` is not fixed at compile time is a C99 feature called VLA that is not part of any C++ standard. You should never use it in C++ code. However, it's supported by some C++ implementations as extensions and if you do want to use it, move the declaration of `int[k]` to after when `k` is known.

Comment: also when I include it in my code what files to i need to include as well?   My ide does not seem to recognize the vector

Comment: @harry47341 to use `std::cin` you use `#include <iostream>` and to use `std::vector` you `#include <vector>`

Comment: `std::` is the [namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) for the [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library). Basically namespaces help make sure your function, variable, and class names to run into ambiguity with other libraries, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Both your programs have two major faults.

1. You need to know the size of an array while creating it. In your code, k is still uninitialized and you are using this value as the size of your array. Instead, change it to

   ```
   int k,i,m,n;
   cin >> k;
   int in[k];
   int reversea[k];
   ```
2. While reversing the array, you should be filling reversea using values from in, and not the other way round. Also, you don't need 2 for loops, just use 1 for loop.

   ```
   for (m=k-1; m>=0; m--){
     reversea[m] = in[k-1-m];       
   }
   ```
3. In the second program, you again need to get the value of k before creating the array input[k].
4. You are testing for equality with a = instead of == . Change your code from

   ```
   if (input[i]=1){
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (input[i] == 1) {
   ```